# Vue.js filterBy to search in multiple fields

Tags: vue.js

How can I filter by searching in multiple search keys?

I'm trying something like this, but (of course) it won't work:

```
<tr v-repeat="questions | filterBy search in 'reference','user.name','shop.shopName'">
```

Comment: Your best option is to write your own custom filter. They are very easy to write: http://vuejs.org/guide/custom-filter.html

Comment: Getting the `keyPath`'s values for the items you're iterating through is a pain in the ass. There's a guide here for doing that: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/case-insensitive-orderby-filter-with-vuejs

Answer (score 7):

The filterBy custom filter is not documented AFAIK, but you can use a `method` to make your own filter:

```js
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
        search: 're',

        people: [
          {name: 'Koos', age: 30, eyes:'red'},
          {name: 'Gert', age: 20, eyes:'blue'},
          {name: 'Pieter', age: 12, eyes:'green'},
          {name: 'Dawid', age: 67, eyes:'dark green'},
          {name: 'Johan', age: 15, eyes:'purple'},
          {name: 'Hans', age: 12, eyes:'pink'}
        ]
    },
    methods: {
      customFilter: function(person) {
          return person.name.indexOf(this.search) != -1
          || person.eyes.indexOf(this.search) != -1
          ;
      }
    },
   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="search"/>
    
    <br/>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>eyes</th>
          <th>age</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr v-for="person in people | filterBy customFilter">
        <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.eyes }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.age }}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This problem resolve with "Computed Properties":

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
        search: '',
        people: [
          {name: 'Koos', age: 30, eyes:'red'},
          {name: 'Gert', age: 20, eyes:'blue'},
          {name: 'Pieter', age: 12, eyes:'green'},
          {name: 'Dawid', age: 67, eyes:'dark green'},
          {name: 'Johan', age: 15, eyes:'purple'},
          {name: 'Hans', age: 12, eyes:'pink'}
        ]
    },
    computed: {
        filteredPerson: function () {
            var self = this;
            return this.people.filter(function (person) {
                return person.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                || person.eyes.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
            });
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="search"/>
    
    <br/>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>eyes</th>
          <th>age</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr v-for="person in filteredPerson">
        <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.eyes }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.age }}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Vue.js version **0.12.11** this is possible with:

```
<li v-repeat="user in users | filterBy searchText in 'name' 'phone'"></li>
```

Make sure to checkout the official guide on this: http://vuejs.org/api/#orderBy

Answer (score 0):

```
 computed: {
            filteredItems() {
                var result = this.accountList;
                if (this.flt.userName != undefined) {
                    result = result.filter(
                        item =>
                            item.userName.toLowerCase().includes(
                                this.flt.userName.toLowerCase()
                            )
                    );
                }
                if (this.flt.tenantId != undefined) {
                    result = result.filter(
                        item =>
                            item.tenantId.includes(
                                this.flt.tenantId
                            )
                    );
                }

                if (this.flt.providerId != undefined) {
                    result = result.filter(
                        item =>
                            item.providerId.includes(
                                this.flt.providerId
                            )
                    );
                } 
                return result;

            }
        },
```