# Search multiple fields in a table in Vue.js with different v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to vue.js. I was trying to filter the table columns using multiple search fields. I have different search fields and their respective v-models for different columns in the table. I want to enable search for each column

I tried the following solutions:
1. [Vue.js filterBy to search in multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157913/vue-js-filterby-to-search-in-multiple-fields)
2. [How do I search through multiple fields in Vue.js 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573098/how-do-i-search-through-multiple-fields-in-vue-js-2)

Using the above two solutions I came up with this:

```
<p>
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input  type="text" placeholder="Enter firstname" v-model="First" />
</p>

<p>
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the last Name" v-model="Last" />
</p>

<p>
  <label>CustomerId</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the CustomerId" v-model="CustomerId" />
</p>


<table id="clients">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="40%">First Name</th>
      <th width="20%">Last Name</th>
      <th width="20%">CustomerId</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody v-for="customer in filteredCustomers.slice(0,20)">

    <tr>
      <td>{{customer.first}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.last}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.id}}</td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Script:

```
export default {
props:['showMod'],

data() {

return {
  id: '',
  First: '',
  Last: '',
  CustomerId: '',
  categories: []
}
},

computed: {

  filteredCustomers: function () {
    var self = this;
    return this.categories.filter(function (cust) {
      return cust.first.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.First.toLowerCase()) >-1 || cust.last.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.Last.toLowerCase()) >-1
  });
  }
```

I change the code to enable search on only one field, it works but stops working when trying to search on multiple fields. 
I don't know what I am doing wrong in this.

Edit:
I was able to get those search working independently by adding "if"

```
  filteredCustomers: function () {
    var self = this;
    return this.categories.filter(function (cust) {
   if (self.First) {
      return cust.first.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.First.toLowerCase()) > -1
   }
    if (self.CustomerId) {
       return cust.clientId.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.CustomerId.toLowerCase()) > -1 
   }

   return cust.last.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.Last.toLowerCase())>-1 
  });
```

Hoewever, I could not get two filter conditions working at the same time like first search based on first name and then search on last name.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to adjust the logic:

```
filteredCustomers() {
    return this.categories.filter(customer => {
        return (!this.First || customer.first.toLowerCase().includes(this.First.toLowerCase()))
            && (!this.Last || customer.last.toLowerCase().includes(this.Last.toLowerCase()))
    });
```

You could also use regular expressions and `.match()` if you didn't want to bother with the lower case conversion.